# ¿Cómo comparar 2 Dataset en C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, datatable, comparaciones

Ambos dataset tienen la misma estructura de campos, necesito pasar al **Dataset 2** los datos del `Dataset 1` que NO se encuentren en el `Dataset 2`.

- Las dos columnas por las que se debe comparar son: **`Dia`** y **`Fecha`**

Suponiendo los siguientes datos:

**Dataset 1:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Dataset 2:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Como se puede observar el dataset 1 contiene el día **Jue. en fecha 04/01/2018** no se encuentra en el dataset 2, por lo tanto necesito pasar solo ese valor al `Dataset 2`.
>
> El **Dataset 2** puede contener datos duplicados (como se puede observar contiene dos veces el dia `Lun. 01/01/2018` ), PERO solo los datos que ya contenía cargado anteriormente.
>
> Ambos dataset contienen 7 filas, pero el resultado final debería ser que el dataset 2 contenga 8 filas luego de agregar el día jueves.

*Lo realicé de la siguiente manera, esta insertando el `Jueves` pero a la vez esta duplicando todos los demás datos:*

```
for (int indice = 0; indice < dataset1.Tables[0].Rows.Count; indice++)
{
     DateTime fecha_ds1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[indice]["Fecha"].ToString());
     string fecha1 = fecha_ds1.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
     string dia1 = dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[indice]["dia"].ToString();

     for (int indice2 = 0; indice2 < dataset2.Tables[0].Rows.Count; indice2++)
     {
         DateTime fecha_ds2 = Convert.ToDateTime(dataset2.Tables[0].Rows[indice2]["Fecha"].ToString());
         string fecha2 = fecha_ds2.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
         string dia2 = dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[indic2]["dia"].ToString();

         if (!fecha1.Equals(fecha2) && !dia1.Equals(dia2))
         {
             //Insertar la fila en Dataset 2 
             break; //y romper el ciclo para volver a tomar
                   //el siguiente valor del primer ciclo.
          }
      }
 }
```

Entonces, **¿Cómo puedo tener un método que solo retornen las filas que no se encuentren en el dataset2, para luego insertarlas?**

> **Nota:** Puede ser retornar un nuevo dataset/datatable con esos datos faltantes.

#### EDITADA:

Usando : **Visual Studio 2010 y Netframework 4**

Comment: Veo que el valor que obtienes para `"Fecha"`, lo conviertes a `string`, luego a `DateTime`, luego otra vez a `string`. ¿Cual es el tipo de ese valor cuando lo sacas directamente del `DataRow`, y por qué tanta conversión?

Comment: De ambos dataset la `fecha` contiene tambien la hora, es tipo `Datetime`, pero no me interesa la hora somo tomo el valor `yyyy/MM/dd` para comparar solo por ese valor, cuando la obtengo del dataset la convierto a Datetime para luego poder darle el formato que deseo, o me sugieres hacerlo con `Split` o `Substrate` ?

Comment: ¿O sea que el valor original es un `string`, no un `DateTime`, pero que incluye la hora, que no quieres?

Comment: El valor del dataset es `Datetime` , la hora me interesa, pero para otra cosa en otro lado, aqui solo utilizo la fecha como tal.

Comment: Aquí encontré un método que devuelves los records en una [respuesta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16863507/8933039) pero la probé y NO FUNCIONA, ademas el método es super largo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la función LINQ [`Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb336390(v=vs.110).aspx) para obtener los `DataRow` del primer dataset que no existen en el segundo.

Lo único es que debes definir una clase que implementa la interfaz [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) que le transmita al `Except` la lógica que debe usar para comparar los data rows.

Puedes definir una clase como la siguiente (puede ser una clase anidada por conveniencia si deseas):

```
class DataRowEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
{
    public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y)
    {
        return ((DateTime)x["Fecha"]).Date == ((DateTime)y["Fecha"]).Date;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DataRow obj)
    {
        return ((DateTime)obj["Fecha"]).Date.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Nota que simplifico la lógica de comparación de fechas, comparado a lo que ya tienes, de las siguientes 2 maneras:

- Ignoro el campo `dia`, porque según puedo ver, si la fecha corresponde, entonces el día va a corresponder también, por lo que me parece redundante verificar este campo adicional.
- Siendo que dices en los comentarios que el tipo del valor `Fecha` ya es un `DateTime`, pero que deseas comparar esta fecha sin tomar en cuenta la porción que incluye la hora, la forma más sencilla de hacer esto es usando la función [`Date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx) de la clase `DateTime`, que de forma directa te da la fecha sin la hora.

Ahora, con esta clase definida, puedes obtener el resultado deseado con la expresión LINQ siguiente:

```
List<DataRow> dataRows =
    dataset1.Tables[0].Rows
        .Cast<DataRow>()
        .Except(dataset2.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>(), new DataRowEqualityComparer())
        .ToList();
```

**Edición**

Si agregas la referencia a `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`, como sugiere Sergio, entonces el código puede ser un poco más "limpio":

```
class DataRowEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
{
    public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y)
    {
        return x.Field<DateTime>("Fecha").Date == y.Field<DateTime>("Fecha").Date;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DataRow obj)
    {
        return obj.Field<DateTime>("Fecha").Date.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

LINQ:

```
List<DataRow> dataRows =
    dataset1.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
        .Except(dataset2.Tables[0].AsEnumerable(), new DataRowEqualityComparer())
        .ToList();
```

**Edición 2**

Si deseas tomar la lista de `DataRow` y agregarlos a tu segundo dataset, asumiendo que ambos dataset tienen una estructura idéntica, puedes hacerlo simplemente así:

```
foreach(var dataRow in dataRows)
{
    dataset2.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dataRow.ItemArray);
}
```

Comment: Solución corta, pero me parece que no me funcionaría de esta manera, estoy utilizando `Visual Studio 2010` y `NetFramework 4`,  las expresiones lambda `=>` en `public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y)
        => ((DateTime)x["Fecha"]).Date == ((DateTime)y["Fecha"]).Date;` me marcan error.  _Nunca he podido entender bien como funciona Linq_

Comment: Ok, ajusté la respuesta. Si no especificas que estás usando una versión mas antigua de C#/.NET, siempre se asume que estás al día.

Comment: Edité la pregunta y agregue la información faltante. Entonces `List<DataRow> dataRows` contrá una lista de las filas que no se encontraron en el dataset2 y esa lista debo asignarla al dataset?  , porque lo que hacia anteriormente es luego recorrer el dataset e ir asignando los valores, _aquí como debo recorrer la lista?_

Comment: Sí, eso es. Y para recorrerlo, solo necesitas un bucle normal: `foreach(DataRow row in dataRows) { /* asigna los valores del "row" al dataSet2 */}`

Comment: Si te sirve, agregué una edición a la respuesta de cómo pudieras agregar y copiar el resultado a tu segundo data set.

Comment: Disculpa la demora, me ocupé pero ya lo he probado, me funciona perfecto. Voy a tener que aprender a usar `LINQ` he notado que todo se hace de forma mas simple!, Gracias...

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas agregar la referencia a [System.Data.DataSetExtensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.aspx)

luego lo tratas con [linq to dataset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb386969(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
        var table0 = data.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();
        var table1 = data.Tables[1].AsEnumerable();

        var combined = table1.Union(table0);
```

Comment: No veo un ejemplo claro en lo que has respondido.  y esto: `var combined = table1.Union(table1);` supongo que debería ser: `var combined = table0.Union(table1);` porque de lo contrario estas uniendo la misma tabla con ella misma.

Comment: cierto lo cambio, union te elimina los duplicados https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb341731(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Pero si me elimina los duplicados, no me eliminara el duplicado que ya contenía el `dataset2` con referencia al `dia Lun.` ?